# Destructure all properties of a combined type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

Is there an easy way, or syntactic sugar to split a combinened type back into a basetype withouth specifying all the properties by hand.

```
type AType = {
  A1Prop: string
  A2Prop: string
  SharedProp: string
}

type BType = {
  B1Prop: string
  B2Prop: string
  SharedProp: string
}

type ABType = AType & BType

const someObject: ABType = {
  A1Prop: 'string',
  A2Prop: 'string',
  B1Prop: 'string',
  B2Prop: 'string',
  SharedProp: 'string'
} 

// destructure here all props of AType
const { A1Prop, A2Prop, SharedProp, ...rest } = someObject
// and split it manually 
const AllPropsOfA : AType = {A1Prop, A2Prop, SharedProp} 
const AllPropsOfB : BType = {...rest, SharedProp}
```

Is there an easier way *without specifying all properties* of `Atype`.
Maybe there is a helper method available? along the lines of: `const AllPropsOfA = GetAllPropsOf<AType>(someObject)`

the resulting object should only contain properties of AType,

```
{
  "A1Prop": "string",
  "A2Prop": "string",
  "SharedProp": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `as` keyword:

```
const aType = someObject as AType;
const bType = someObject as BType;
```

Comment: I'm trying to split the properties in order to pass them to a function that should not receive the the splitted properties. for example: `console.log(AllPropsOfA) logs:  {
  "A1Prop": "string",
  "A2Prop": "string",
  "SharedProp": "string"
}` while `console.log(someObject as AType) logs: {
  "A1Prop": "string",
  "A2Prop": "string",
  "B1Prop": "string",
  "B2Prop": "string",
  "SharedProp": "string"
} `, 
In this cases having the B props in the result is unwanted. (i'll add that to the question)

Comment: To my knowledge then, the only way is the method you've shown - de-structuring. TypeScript cannot make properties disappear from an object once they are set initially, they will always be present. What you can do is change the interpretation of how TypeScript looks at an object which is where the `as` keyword comes in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking only for type-level side solution, `someObject` is perfectly assignable to both `AType` and `BType` variables without any hustle:

```ts
type AType = {
  A1Prop: string
  A2Prop: string
  SharedProp: string
}

type BType = {
  B1Prop: string
  B2Prop: string
  SharedProp: string
}

type ABType = AType & BType

const someObject: ABType = {
  A1Prop: 'string',
  A2Prop: 'string',
  B1Prop: 'string',
  B2Prop: 'string',
  SharedProp: 'string'
} 

const AllPropsOfA : AType = someObject // ok
const AllPropsOfB : BType = someObject // ok
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKkADW)

Types are kind of *open* in typescript and unless you trigger [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) you're fine assigning more concrete type to the more general one.

---

Though if your question is about runtime manipulations then things get a bit more complicated. Types do not exist in runtime and you're left only with some sort of hacks and workarounds.

```ts
const ATypeProps = ['A1Prop', 'A2Prop', 'SharedProp'] as const
const BTypeProps = ['B1Prop', 'B2Prop', 'SharedProp'] as const

type ATypeKeys = typeof ATypeProps[number]
type BTypeKeys = typeof BTypeProps[number]

type AType = { [K in ATypeKeys]: string }
type BType = { [K in BTypeKeys]: string }


const someObject = {
  A1Prop: 'string',
  A2Prop: 'string',
  B1Prop: 'string',
  B2Prop: 'string',
  SharedProp: 'string'
}

const pick = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: readonly K[]): Pick<T, K> => {
  const result = {} as Pick<T, K>
  keys.forEach((key) => result[key] = obj[key])
  return result
}

const AllPropsOfA: AType = pick(someObject, ATypeProps)
/* {
  "A1Prop": "string",
  "A2Prop": "string",
  "SharedProp": "string"
} */


const AllPropsOfB: BType = pick(someObject, BTypeProps)
/* {
  "B1Prop": "string",
  "B2Prop": "string",
  "SharedProp": "string"
} */
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9bgm)